# how can i use express.js variables into sql queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am new in node.js
I am trying to make a login and registration system using express.js, vanilla JS, CSS, HTML, and `MySql`.

below is code that handles routing as well as parses HTTP Post requests made by the client which consists of username and password. username and password are stored inside `fields.username` and `fields.password`

functions `userRegistration(...)` and `userLogin(...)` are defined inside db.js ( shown at the end ); they are exported from `db.js` and are imported in `users.js`

**users.js**

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var userInfoArray = [fields.username, fields.password]
    db.userRegistration(userInfoArray)
  })
});

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var userInfoArray = [fields.username, fields.password]
    db.userLogin(userInfoArray)
  })
});
```

I have created `userinfo` table to store usernames and passwords.
As shown below I am getting username and password by HTTP post method. Which I am parsing using
***formidable module*** which gives me `fields.username` and `fields.password` values.
I am using query(...) method to query database providing actual SQL as string named `registrationQueryString` (to insert an entry into table) and `loginQueryString`(to find whether provided username and password are in the database or not)

**db.js**

```
var username, password;
var userInfoArray = [username, password]
const registrationQueryString = "INSERT INTO (username, password) userinfo VALUES ( ?, ? )"
const loginQueryString = "SELECT (username, password) FROM userinfo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT (username, password) FROM userinfo WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?))"
function userRegistration (userInfoArray){
    dbConnection.query( registrationQueryString, userInfoArray, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(results)
    })
}
function userLogin (userInfoArray){
    dbConnection.query( loginQueryString, userInfoArray, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(results)
    })
}
```

It is giving me an error

> "wer" is random value I provided as username and password

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(username, password) userinfo VALUES ( 'wer', 'wer' )' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (F:\dr.server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at Object.userRegistration (F:\dr.server\db.js:29:18)
    at F:\dr.server\routes\users.js:12:8
    at zalgoSafe (F:\dr.server\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:20:10)
    at f (F:\dr.server\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (F:\dr.server\node_modules\formidable\src\Formidable.js:183:9)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (F:\dr.server\node_modules\formidable\src\Formidable.js:612:10)
    at QuerystringParser.<anonymous> (F:\dr.server\node_modules\formidable\src\plugins\querystring.js:36:10) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(username, password) userinfo VALUES ( 'wer', 'wer' )' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO (username, password) userinfo VALUES ( 'wer', 'wer' )"
}
```

I know that something is wrong with my SQL queries but I am not able to figure it out.
Any help will be welcomed.
If this information isn't enough I can give specific code through github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to add a comment, yet. Have you tried to change your SQL statement to:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_name, col_name) VALUES ('value', 'value')

"INSERT INTO userinfo (username, password) VALUES ( 'wer', 'wer' )"
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

**Edit**:

In your post:

> It is giving me an error
>
> I know that something is wrong with my SQL queries but I am not able to figure it out.

The code above is not meant to be the answer. As I previously mentioned, not able to comment, yet. The above code is just a pointer to the correct answer. You have to change your MySQL query to the syntax above. The link provided gives you the correct syntax.

Comment: you are hardcoding the SQL which will certainly not work in case of login registration process. The whole point of question is to find a way to embed multiple express.js variables into SQL

Comment: if you see more precisely in the last line of error you can see the SQL format which caused error. you are sharing the same format.

Comment: @Het Tarkhala if you look closely, the syntax is different. Switch the tbl_name and (col_name, ...)

Comment: that was a perfect solution, i didnt understand the documentation (it was too noisy !) thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals to do so.

```
var username, password;
const registrationQueryString = `INSERT INTO (username, password) userinfo VALUES ('${username}', '${password}')`
```

And then use `registrationQueryString` as a raw query.

Bear in mind this is an ES2015 feature and should be available in any recent version of Node.js. More about template literals at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

"insert into `userinfo`(username, password) values('wer', 'wer');"

Answer (score 0):

First update this query from

```
INSERT INTO (username, password) userinfo VALUES ( ?, ? )
```

to

```
INSERT INTO userinfo (username, password) VALUES ( ?, ? )
```

Please don't use this type of query

```
SELECT (username, password) FROM userinfo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT (username, password) FROM userinfo WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?))
```

Replace it with the following

```
const ObjQr = [
        req.body.username,
        req.body.password
    ];
const SsQl = "CALL SpSelectUser(?,?)";
    query(SsQl, ObjQr, (err,results,fields) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send('ERROR');
        }
        else {
            const Info= {
                UserInfo : results[0]
            };
            res.json(Info);
        }
    });
```

Try to use StoredProcedure instead of direct query to avoid race condition and Sql-Injection.